# Local variable in function overlaps and clobbers memory space of static global variable defined in shared object

Tags: c, unix, gcc, shared-libraries, dlopen

In my C project, I have a shared library compiled with `-fPIC` that contains several static data structures declared at global scope, including, let's say,

`static struct mydata;`

This library calls a function

```
void myfunc() {
char foo[2048] = {0};
...
}
```

which is defined in a different shared library.

When I compile my main application, I link in the shared library that defines `myfunc()`. At runtime, the main application loads the other shared library containing the static data structures using `dlopen()`.

Calling `myfunc()` from the shared library in which `mydata` is declared results in `mydata` being at least partially overwritten.

After snooping with `gdb` it is clear that the local array `foo` is placed in memory in such a way that it overlaps with the address of `mydata`, so when the array is initialized to 0, so too is `mydata`.

How could this be? Am I doing something that is unhandled by the compiler?

Note that I am running Red Hat on 64-bit architecture using gcc 4.6.

Comment: I don't believe the compiler will put a global variable within 2 kb of the stack (at least not in the direction the stack is growing towards).

Comment: I wouldn't think so either, that's why I'm here. If I break at the function call and print the addresses of both objects in gdb I can see that the address of the struct is right on top of the range of addresses for the local array.

Comment: You could try reserving more memory for the stack (apparently via `setrlimit` on Linux, for example)

Comment: Unless you seriously messed up the `struct mydata`'s size somehow (get different definitions in the various files), or you *really* wrote as above (that just declares a structure tag, if the compiler accepts that as-is it is a compiler bug)...

Answer (score 0):

> How could this be?

I've seen this happen ... when some other routine reserved 8MB buffer on the stack, and overflowed stack into the data region.

If the problem goes away with `ulimit -s unlimited`, chances are that's what is happening to you as well.

At the place where `mydata` has just been corrupted, do these commands:

```
(gdb) p $rsp
(gdb) p $rbp
(gdb) p &mydata
(gdb) p &foo[0]
(gdb) info var mydata
```

and update your question with results.